# how to make vehicle or train move across the scene in iOS Sprite Kit Game with swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to implement iOS application with alphabet train in the sprite kit game scene in swift. I am not sure how to keep sprite node train wheel rotating and to connect it with the train sprite node, to achieve real train movement across the scene. I can create sprite nodes and present the the scene correctly, but unsure of the right approach processing, where train and wheel are connected and moving togehter. Do I need to use anything extra in addition to the SKActions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the wheels and all pieces of the train as children of a main `SKNode` which represents the whole train. You can move that across the screen and simply handle rotation on the wheels.

```
let train = SKNode()    // add move actions to this
let wheel = SKSPriteNode(imageNamed: "wheel") // add rotation actions to this
train.addChild(wheel)
```

Comment: So far so good. Not sure how to "add move actions to this" and "add rotation actions to this". I thought there have to be some kind of joint made between train and wheel so that they are tied together.

Comment: By adding it to the train, that's what you're doing.
You should read the SpriteKit docs from apple if you don't know what actions are.